# Best way to utilize navigation property in EF core inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-core, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

here is my question:

I have an "Admin" class which can inherit from "*ServiceUser (abstract)*" however i'd rather abstain from doing so.
Here's the class diagram:

In "Account" I have to set up the navigation properties.
"Admin Account" inherits indirectly from Account.
pic below :
[image: class diagram]

Here's my solution so far but it seems messy.

```cs
public abstract class Account<T> where T : ServiceUser
{
    // some fields from the class diagram
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    
    public T AccountOwner { get; set; }
    // how to set up this ^ ?
}
```

What would be the best way to set up this navigation property so that Accounts may contain a reference to the Customer, Seller or Admin?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. The diagram is fine, although it's very compressed/blurry at 100%, but your `Account` class should be done in a code block and not an image.

Comment: Thank you for your input.
I will try and swap it to code, it's my first post here

Comment: jesus how do i get this image to work now